# packages are already satisfied but can not import them

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to use pandas on jupyter-notebook. it is using python3.
when I use

```
import pandas as pd
```

it says:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

but when I use:

```
pip install pandas
```

it returns:

> Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (0.24.2)

how can I import packages like this. it is set to use python3 but for pip command it see python2.7

Comment: I assume you use Anaconda. It comes with its own environment. Please try this: 
conda install -c anaconda pandas

Comment: are you sure you dont have multiple copies of python? you might be installing pandas into the wrong one. easiest way to test this is probably run python from the same window you run pip and try to import pandas there

Comment: I don't have conda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, you are running several python versions in your PC. The environment value `pip` indicate to `Python 2.7`. However, you want use `pandas` module in your `Python 3`.

**One solution:**

Find the `pip.py` of your `python 3` local address. Then add this address of `pip.py` to your PC environment as environment name with `pip3`.

The rest operation is the same:
in CMD:
`$ pip3 install pandas`

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, this operation is not recommended. Because some orders will conflict in CMD, or you need to change the name of the conflicted file. Therefore, it is time to use anaconda. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`pip3 install pandas`

Otherwise download **Anaconda**

Answer (score 0):

I think, this may be due to, you may have not added path of the site packages path to windows environment variables. 
add `PATH = '...\Python36\lib\site-packages'` to windows environment variables.

to add the paths to windows environment. 
refer to : https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are adding pandas to the wrong environment. You might have more than one python installed. Open your anaconda prompt (if you are using windows as soon as you type cmd or anaconda in search you should have the command prompt console or or anaconda prompt depends of what you type) then use the following:

```
  conda install -c anaconda pandas
```

if you are you using the ananconda environment it is better to use conda install.