# Python requests module appears to be Installed, but not found

Tags: python, python-requests, python-module

I am trying to `import requests`

But when I try to run it in PyCharm (or even terminal) I get:

[image]

As a note, my PyCharm interpreter is listed as:

[image]

Things I've tried.

- I started by trying `sudo pip install requests` and `sudo pip3 install requests` both of which give:

[image]

- Everything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56125835/packages-are-already-satisfied-but-can-not-import-them), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17309288/importerror-no-module-named-requests%5D), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57859673/modulenotfounderror-requests-despite-installation-attemps-showing-requirement)
- uninstalling and reinstalling requests via `pip uninstall requests` then `pip install requests` as well as `pip3 uninstall requests` then `pip3 install requests`
- The terminal command `pip3 list` gives the most recent version of requests
  [image]
- The terminal commands `which python` and `which python3` both return `/Users/chad/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3`

I'm on MacOS 11.6 and totally lost.

Comment: "As a note, my PyCharm interpreter is listed as:" "The terminal commands which python and which python3 both return /Users/chad/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3" Notice how those paths are *different*? If you want the Anaconda install to be your "default" Python, and have `requests` installed there, and then want PyCharm to use that, then the problem is *telling PyCharm about that install*.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, thank you. I suspected that difference may be an issue, but I don't know how to _not_ make Anaconda the default? I've tried in the past, but it just seems to break everything, so I end up basically nuking the whole thing, uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda.

Comment: Like I said, if you *do* want it to be the default, then just tell PyCharm to use it.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click that little + ... then install your package... that will guarantee its the same interpretter pycharm is using

[image]

Comment: This appears to have worked! Thank you so much! I spent my entire morning and part of my afternoon on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the installation you installed `requests` for `python3.8`, but you are trying to run `json_test.py` with `python3.9`.

Try installing requests using `pip3.9`, or use a virtualenv to install all your dependencies and use that to launch your application.