# Python "No module named 'awsiot'" despite being installed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I've looked up many [versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56125835/packages-are-already-satisfied-but-can-not-import-them) of this problem, I don't think I'm falling for any obvious pitfalls, even using a virtual environment. Starting to wonder if there's something weird with this particular package.

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate

pip install awsiot
ls venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ | grep awsiot
>>> awsiot-0.1.3.dist-info
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
>>> ['', '/usr/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.10', '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/home/lexfridman/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

It's installed, it's in a directory that sys.path knows about, in a fresh venv. Yet:

```
python -c "import awsiot"

>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
>>>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>>> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsiot'
```

Same process yields same result on a different linux machine. What could be causing this? Can anyone recreate?

Comment: What distribution and what version of that distribution are you using?

Comment: 3.10, and 3.8 on the other machine

Answer (score 5):

Solution: name in pip install command appears to be different:

```
pip install awsiotsdk
```

And now `import awsiot` works.

Is it normal for these two commands to use different names? I used `pipreqs .` and `pip install -r requirements.txt` initially, which makes the same mistake and assumes `pip install awsiot` is what it needs to do.